# npm install doesn't create subfolder in npm_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I've downloaded the foundation 6 Sass Version.
Now I want to add some more gulp plugins to my node_modules folder.

I've navigated to my foundation root folder and typed the command

```
sudo npm install --save gulp-uglify
```

into the terminal. Now it installs all the stuff into the node_modules folder but without creating the subfolder "gulp-uglify". Consequently there are hundreds of files and folders in my node_modules folder.

Thanks for your help.
Robin

Comment: Can you share the files you see?

Comment: sure, this is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/iam-robin/scaffolding_foundation with the uninstalled uglify plugin.

Comment: @iamrobin. It installs fine for me and creates `node_modules/gulp-uglify` subfolder. Of course there are hundreds of other subdirectories in `node_modules` because of npm@3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/33024131/2424184 But if there's no such subfolder, can you commit your `node_modules` to this repo and also share which npm version you use?